# Reading .csv and .xlsx in a directory using Data frame

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, xls, pathlib

How to read all files in a directory if the directory contains .csv and .xlsx files?

I tried:

```
read_files = Path(path).rglob("*.csv","*.xlsx")
all_files = [pd.read_excel(file) for file in read_files]
```

But it is not working. How can I achieve it?

Comment: By reading and learning. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html, https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html

Comment: Also this: https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: @Rahul , this is a good question if considered as how to (efficiently) read both types of files

Answer (score 0):

The `rglob` method of `pathlib.Path` accepts exactly one pattern. You can (somewhat inefficiently) loop twice:

```
pathobj = Path(path)
read_files = pathobj.rglob("*.csv") + pathobj.rglob("*.xlsx")
```

or refactor the code to use a different traversal function - `os.walk` comes to mind, or do an `rglob` on all files (or all files with a dot in their name) and extract only the ones which match either of your patterns:

```
read_files = filter(lambda x: x.suffix in ('.xls', '.csv'), Path(path).rglob("*.*"))
```

Like the documentation already tells you, the pattern syntax supported by `rglob` is the same as for [the `fnmatch` module.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch)

... Though as it turns out, using `read_excel` for CSV files is probably not the way to go anyway; try

```
pathobj = Path(path)
all_files = [pd.read_csv(file) for file in pathobj.rglob("*.csv")]
all_files.extend(pd.read_excel(file) for file in pathobj.rglob("*.xlsx"))
```

Comment: Thank You Sir!!Can pd.read_excel can be used to convert files in read_files to data frame?

Comment: I'm not a Pandas person but that part of your code looks fine to my untrained eye; does it not work for you?

Comment: I am getting unsupported operand type error!

Comment: That seems unrelated to anything in the code here. Probably (accept this answer, or post one of your own and accept that if you prefer, and) ask a new question with enough details to reproduce the problem. In my brief test, `read_excel` does not seem to be able to read a plain-jane CSV file, so you will have to use a different reader function for CSV files. Thankfully, I have no Excel files to test on.

Comment: See update now for a method which calls `read_csv` for the CSV files.